# .htaccess modrewrite breaks my forms

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added a modrewrite to my .htaccess and now all of my forms don't send post data to php scripts.

Code:
eg: my .htaccess removes the .php extension, removes the trailing slash if it's a directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect index to site root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

**Is there a way of adding exceptions to the modrewrite rules so certain files/directories are ignored?** So all files called form-process.php, email-process.php, upload-process.php, save-process.php could be ignored?

edit: I've just been reading that I can add !POST to my query. If I add it like this, would it work?

```
# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ !POST
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f !POST
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

edit: also added [QSA] to the rules above, but still no variables are passed to my forms

**edit: For anyone else stuck with this problem I fixed it by selecting the files that posted data and removing them from the changes to the .htaccess file. It's not ideal, but it works for now.**

```
# ignore recipes page
RewriteRule ^directorytoremove - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^filenametoremove - [L,NC]
```

Redirect 301 does not pass any data via POST, even if you add QSA. So you need to do a post-redirect-get eg your form POSTS the data, is redirected and the receiving file GETS the data and processes it. If you are having the same problem, paste the code above at the top of your .htaccess file below the opening RewriteEngine On statement.

Hope that helps anyone with the same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a rule like this in the beginning (just after the `RewriteEngine on`)

```
RewriteRule ^(form|email|upload|save)-process\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me 404 errors for the selected pages. Does that mean the rules below are still being processed? I thought [L] stopped that from being processed further?

Comment: [L] stops the rules comming after the current one from beeing processed, if you are still getting 404 try to clear your browser cache and post your edited code please (be sure that the files does exist too)

Comment: I've had some success using `RewriteRule ^directoryname - [L,NC]` to remove directories from the rewrite. I wonder if I can do the same for individual files as you have above. Thanks Yazmat! :)

Comment: Of course you can, I am sure that it is just a simple thing that is messing around and generating the 404.

Comment: are those files in the root dir ? and the htaccess where it is ?

Comment: No they weren't in the root. I've worked around the problem by ignoring each individual file. It's not ideal, but it works, so I'm happy! Thank you again for all your help @Yazmat ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what the QSA line does please?

Comment: appends QUERY_STRING.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: I've updated the code above with QSA, but still no change. Have I placed QSA in the correct place?